# symfony 4 api suddenly becomes very slow

Tags: php, mysql, symfony4, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I am here to ask for your help with a problem I am having with Symfony 4.

Indeed I develop a rest API with Symfony 4, everything worked super well until today when calls to the API become very slow.

First he gave me the following error:  **Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98570240 bytes) in /home/user/tlt_symfony_back/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php on line 186
2019-03-20T12:55:19+01:00[critical] Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98570240 bytes)**

that I solved by setting **memory_limit** to **512M** in **php.ini** but calls take too long before answering. With Postman it closes the window completely.

I use **FOSRestBundle** with **Jms_serializer** .

Thank you in advance for your help.

This is a sample code for getting for instance all the announcements:

```
public function getAnnonces(Request $request, ObjectManager $manager){

    $annonces = $manager->getRepository(Annonces::class)->findAll();

    if(!$annonces)
        return new JsonResponse([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Il existe aucune annonce'
        ]);

    return $annonces;

}
```

And Annonces Entity has basic attributes:
title : string, 
type: string, 
user : ManyToOne relation with user Entity

Database : Mysql.

Comment: My guess based on the first memory error is you are retrieving a very large resultset

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, I try to delete all data and keep just one, but there is the same problem and before it worked with all these data.

Answer (score 0):

try to dump $annonces just after repository call, is there really a lightweight object? Try to get one announcement with

```
$annonces = $manager->getRepository(Annonces::class)->find(1);
```

Do you need the Doctrine entities with relations here? If not, try to fetch the contents s arrays

```
$qb = $manager->createQueryBuilder();
$annonces = $qb->select('a')->from(Annonces::class, 'a')->getQuery()->getResult(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, finally I find the problem it was due to a lot of relations between my tables and serializer took long time to serialize, so I use now native sql queries with join to get only the fields I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If problem occurs without any source code changes it means it was from the beginning, but it's scale wasn't noticible by you.

My first shot would be checking the database relations. For example, if you have OneToMany relation which fetch="EAGER" or fetch="LAZY" and you have a lot of elements in right side table it will slow down querying the left side table. You can do a simple check is that a problem adding fetch="EXTRA_ LAZY" to each OneToMany and ManyToMany relation in the Annonces entity.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_onetomany

If this won't help I suggest you to check the table indexes.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, finally I find the problem it was due to a lot of relations between my tables and serializer took long time to serialize, so I use now native sql queries with join to get only the fields I need.